# Scatter plot color based on metric in plotly in R

Tags: r, plotly

I am using scatter plot and I want to change metric CYI to Green color and metric LYI to red color.

```
library(plotly)
dataset <- data.frame(SC = c("A","B","C","D"),
                      CYI =  c(100,150,180,80),
                      LYI = c(80,120,190,90)
)

CYI_Text <- paste("Status Category = ", dataset$SC, "<br>",
                  "Current Year Interaction = ", dataset$CYI, "<br>")
LYI_Text <- paste("Status Category = ", dataset$SC, "<br>",
                  "Last Year Interaction = ", dataset$LYI, "<br>")

g <- plot_ly(dataset, x = dataset$SC, y = dataset$CYI, mode = 'markers' , marker = list(size =20) ) %>%
  add_trace(x= dataset$SC, y = dataset$CYI , type = 'scatter', hoverinfo = "text", text = CYI_Text, color ="red", showlegend = FALSE) %>%
  add_trace(x= dataset$SC, y = dataset$LYI , type = 'scatter', hoverinfo = "text", text = LYI_Text, color ="green", showlegend = TRUE)
g
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: wrap `color = 'red'` in `marker = list(color = 'red')`

Comment: Thank you so much for quick response.